# SOQL query to get All the Note of a account

Tags: soql

1. How can I retrieve all `Note` records for a particular `Account` using SOQL?
2. How can I retrieve all `Opportunity` records for a particular `Contact` using SOQL?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

to be more familiar with such queries read next [first](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using), [second](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)

> How to retrieve all the Note of a particular Account using SOQL query

Here are child relationship helps

```
select Id, (
    select Id, Body
    from Notes
    )
from Account
where Id = :desiredAccountId
```

> How to retrieve all the opportunity of a particular Contact using SOQL Query

```
select Id
from Opportunity
where AccountId in (
    select AccountId
    from Contact
    where Id = :desiredContactId
    )
```

Comment: This will only work if there's a relationship established as a field in the outer object... or so it seems.  If there's only a child relationship established (for cascading deletes, for example), and not an explicit named relationship, it's considered an "arbitrary join" and is not supported in SOQL.

Answer (score 0):

For getting Notes you can use next query:

```
SELECT Id, Title 
FROM Note 
WHERE parentid = :account.Id
```

For Opportunities related to Contact - if you use OpportunityContactRole object for connecting these objects, you can use such query:

```
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Contact.Name
     FROM OpportunityContactRoles
     WHERE ContactId = :contact.Id)
FROM Opportunity
```